# How do I get the ActiveSheet from an Embedded Excel API if the sheet tab is disabled?

Tags: excel, onedrive

If have an Excel sheet from one drive embedded in a page via the EWA api's.  (microsoft's)  Ordinarily, this code works:

```
    var instance = Ewa.EwaControl.getInstances().getItem(0);
    var workbook = instance.getActiveWorkbook();
    var sheet = workbook.getActiveSheet();
```

I.e. "sheet" will refer to the actual sheet, where I can make requests like "sheet.getRange(...)"

The problem happens when we have tabs/sheetlist turned off.  I.e. "Sheet1", "Sheet2", etc. don't show up as expected.  The problem is that "sheet" is null.  I.e. a sheet is visible/usable, but "workbook.getActiveSheet()" returns null.

How can I get the active sheet?

Answer (score 0):

**Solution**: Just use the same commands you expected to find on an EWA sheet, from the EWA WorkBook.

1. If you have sheets disabled. (I.e. a user cannot see other the sheet list to click on anything)

   - the sheet list and getActiveSheet ***will*** be null.
2. The workbook itself assumes the role of all the sheet commands, like getRange and getRangeAsync.
3. Side Notes:

   - You cannot tell it to change active sheets in this mode.
   - You can have multiple excel sheets open and interacting on the same page